# Server Side Processing Dynamic Columns

Tags: c#, datatables-1.10

Server side path provides a 404 error where path is same as used on initial loading of the table.  The table is destroyed and the columns are dynamically changed.

I successfully apply server side processing where I have static columns.  I have previously built the table dynamically without server side processing but the load is too large now for it to handle.  Therefore I have moved to SQL paging with server side processing configuration but it will not load the table even thought the path is the same as it is when I initially load the table but with one static column. I am using version 1.10.15 due to how long I have been using the library and I have many tables that I am concerned will no longer work if I upgrade.  Not sure upgrading will fix the problem either.

JQuery Datatables code

```
var oTable = $("#InvoiceProcessing").DataTable({
                jQueryUI: true,
                pagingType: "full_numbers",
                responsive: true,
                "scrollX": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "@Url.Action("GetInvoiceProcessing", "InvoiceProcessing")?clientId=" + cId + "&summaryDate=" + sumDate + "&processedDate=" + procDate + "&accountNumber=&invoiceNumber=",
                "bProcessing": true,
                "destroy": true,
                lengthMenu: [[25, 50, 100], [25, 50, 100]],
                "autoWidth": true
            });
```

C# method signature - This method does not get hit

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetInvoiceProcessing(Guid? clientId, DateTime? summaryDate, DateTime? processedDate, DataTableParamModel param, string accountNumber = "", string invoiceNumber = "")
```

I need to have the paging reflect the full size of the query.  I am using sql paging which returns a total record count and only the page length of data.  If I can accomplish this without server side processing I would be happy with that as well.

Comment: Ok, so I have the data loading but it is not doing it correctly.  The paging is not working.  It is being set to only the number of records instead of the total count.  The number of records to display is 25 and the total count is 140.  I am setting the paging in the following manner iTotalRecords = 140, iTotalDisplayRecords = 140

Comment: It only has a problem with the path when I destroy the table, recreate the table with new columns, and then attempt to reinitialize with server side processing.

Comment: Have you gone through [this link](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/40690/sample-implementation-of-serverside-processing-in-c-mvc-ef-with-paging-sorting-searching) which shows a sample datatables server-side processing with MVC C#?

Comment: Yes, I have viewed that answer but I do not think it suits my need.  My columns change from client to client and therefore are not static.  They are different for each client both in number and name.  I have also tried to add them in the initialization via the columns attribute / property by supplying Jason string but that gives me an error.   I will have to provide another ist with that error later.  This work is outside work from my job and I am at work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use the information Priyank Panchal supplied but modifying the solution in the suggestion to meet my needs.

I was not able to use it as is because the columns I generate for the grid are dynamically driven by the data and therefore cannot be predefined before loading.

Do to that I have to load the grid three different ways.

1. First I load it with only one field that identifies it's usage with the Datatables default message of "No Available Records".
2. The second load recreates the grid after a selection of the client, which is what determines the fields required, and it reloads with the proper structure.
3. Lastly, I reload the grid with another selection by the user that defines how the data is filtered.

With this there is also the requirement to hide the first column, which I do through the "columnDefs" attribute of the Datatables configuration.

The last requirement was to provide to additional fields for edit and delete buttons.

This was accomplished through the "columnDefs" attribute as well along with referencing the table in the following manner: "aTargets": [oTable.columns()[0].length - 2].  This provided the ability to add it first to last column and another after it.